# file upload with multer that contains input name array

Tags: node.js, pug, multer

i am uploading files with multer nodejs. Everything Works fine but when input type="file" contains name="warranty[][warantycopy]" i am unable to access this file.
Below is my code in index.js:

```
var multer  = require('multer');
var invoice_copies = '';
var storage_Copies = multer.diskStorage({

  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    // console.log("fileefefef");
    // console.log(file);
    cb(null, 'uploads/'+file.fieldname)
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    invoice_copies=(file.originalname).replace(/ /g,"_")
    cb(null, invoice_copies)
  }
});

var uploadCopies = multer({ storage: storage_Copies })
```

post request contains this code

```
router.post('/vehicle-battery',uploadCopies.fields([{name:'invoice_copy1'},
    {name:'warrantyDetails'}]), function(req, res) {
```

//my code
}
my jade file is :

```
 form#formAddUser(name="addVehicle",method="post",action="/vehicle-battery",enctype="multipart/form-data")
        input(type="file", name="invoice_copy1",class="form-control")
        input#warrantyCard(type="text", placeholder="warranty Card Number", name="warrantyDetails[0][warrantyCardNumber]",class="form-control")
        input#warrantyCardExpiry(type="text", placeholder="warranty Card Expiry in Month", name="warrantyDetails[0][warrantyCardExpiry]",class="form-control")
        input#warrantyCardCopy(type="file", placeholder="warranty Card Expiry copy", name="warrantyDetails[0][warrantyCardCopy]",class="form-control")
        textarea(placeholder="Particulars" name="battery_paticulars")
        button#btnSubmit(type="submit",class="form-control") submit
```

if i am using

```
input#warrantyCardCopy(type="file", placeholder="warranty Card Expiry copy", name="warrantyDetails",class="form-control")
```

this code working fine.

Comment: after working for research  for so long time i solved it . I am providing my solution so that it can help someone else. i have used router.post('/vehicle-battery',uploadCopies.any(), function(req, res) { //my code }

Answer (score 1):

From a comment above:

after working for research for so long time i solved it . I am providing my solution so that it can help someone else. i have used

```
router.post('/vehicle-battery',uploadCopies.any(), function(req, res) { //my code }
```